# React how to make an input field with a fixed value combined with a dynamic value

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hooks, fetch, react-bootstrap

Any solutions on how I can achieve similar results like this guy does with Javascript in React? Check link -> https://codepen.io/matheusls94/pen/WOdRPR

I have an inputfield/textfield(mui) which makes a post request to the server when a new user wants to register a  new account/e-mail address. I want the user to avoid typing "@hotmail.com" which should be a fixed value that is uneditable/unremovable in the input field. Like in the codepen  link above.

Dynamic value example -> Testemail, fixed value -> @hotmail.com

```
  const [email, setEmail]=useState("");

 async function Register(e){
    let item = {email};
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);

    let result = await fetch("https://localhost:44334/api/Register",{
        method:"POST",
        headers:{
            "Accept": "text/plain",
            "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json",
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(item),
    });
    result = await result.json();

return (
<>
 <Container className="mt-5">
            <Row>
                <Col lg={4} md={6} sm={12} className="text-center mt-5 p-3">
                    <img className="icon-img" src={loginIcon} alt="icon"/>
                    <Form onSubmit={Register}>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Label>E-Mail</Form.Label>
                            <input value={dynamicvalue+fixedvalue} type="text" required={true} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}  fullWidth />
                        </Form.Group>
</>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could append `"@hotmail.com"` to the `value` prop of the input and strip it out when updating state. Check if the input value ends with `"@hotmail.com"` and if it does allow the state to be updated.

Example

```js
function App() {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    if (value.endsWith("@hotmail.com")) {
      const modValue = value.replace("@hotmail.com", "");
      setEmail(modValue);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={`${email}@hotmail.com`}
        onChange={changeHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

### Update

> How would I achieve this if the values in modValue was to include
> "@hotmail.com" ? instead of replacing it with an empty string? For
> some reason the input value "@hotmail.com" does not get included on
> the registered user, only the dynamic value.

Correct. You would need to append `"@hotmail.com"` back to the `email` value if using elsewhere.

But you are correct, there's a way to initialize the `email` state `"@hotmail.com"` and do the same `.endsWith` test and state update without the string replace.

```js
function App() {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("@hotmail.com");

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    if (value.endsWith("@hotmail.com")) {
      setEmail(value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={email}
        onChange={changeHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Good explanation, How would I achieve this if the values in modValue was to include "@hotmail.com" ? instead of replacing it with an empty string? For some reason the input value "@hotmail.com" does not get included on the registered user, only the dynamic value.

Comment: @Demaru There is a way to do that. I've added to my answer, please do check it out.

Comment: Ahhh okay now I see how to do it, learned something new today as a junior developer, thank you, very much appreciated.